# I am accessing QC API through OTA but after deployment it says "Unable to connect to HPCQ server"

Tags: c#, ota, hp-quality-center

The code works perfect in debug mode but after getting deployed and running it gives error "unable to connect to HPQC server". Following are the details:

1. I am using QC 10.0
2. I have used OTA API and not Site Admin API
3. What is required to register on server for OTA API? My server has QC client installed. Besides that what else is needed?
4. I have added the reference TDAPIOLELib

Answer (score 0):

OTA depends on OTACLIENT.DLL and WEBCLIENT.DLL. Make that your deployment server has both DLLs registered and that the versions of the DLLs match that of the HPQC/HPALM server that you're connecting to.

I've found that using the built-in download client components registers the DLLs only for the current user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register OTAClient.Dll onto your server using regsvr32.

Also when you debug, Visual studio runs the application in 32 bit mode. Make sure your deployed application works in 32 bit mode only.